# What are are the required steps of modeling an irregular 3d polyhedron

Tags: opengl, glut

What are the basic steps of modeling an irregular 3d polyhedron (example "[pentagonal hexecontahedron](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Pentagonal+Hexecontahedron&dataset=)") with GLUT?

What I understand so far is that I need to determine vertices of the object. How? 
What's next when I have the vertex list? How do I use the glVertex(..) function to draw the polyhedron?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would to make the model in a 3d modeling program, unless you want to figure out all the vertices by hand which would be a pain. Use the vertex data from the saved file and put it into an array that you can either figure out how to read from file, or just make a static array in a header with all the vertex data in.

then you can use vertex arrays to render the model in one swoop http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/CodeColony/vertexarrays.php